# Flutter Application Crash After Adding Dependencies

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a flutter project. I use firebase as the database and I want to send cloud notification using it. After adding firebase_messaging dependency, my application does not open. This is the error which it displays. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this just Read this Docs.

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

https://medium.com/flutterpub/enabling-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notifications-with-flutter-39b08f2ed723

This will Solve your issue.

Comment: Share your Code

Comment: Sir,dependencies:
  cloud_firestore:
  google_sign_in:
  firebase_storage:
  fluttertoast:
  shared_preferences:
  image_picker:
  cached_network_image:
  intl:
  firebase_auth:
  calendarro: ^1.0.0
  unicorndial:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

Comment: These are my dependencies. Crash comes after adding firebase_messaging dependency. Which part of the code do you need sir?

Comment: if possible send me the whole project